# Print one variable values together in the loop with Python

Tags: python, pandas

How to print one variable values togehter in the loop?

I have a dataframe with some columns, then I loop though based on classification value, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\example..csv')

classif = list(set(data['clasification']))
# print(classif)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

for classif in classif:
    df_r = data[data['clasification'] == classif]

    Y = df_r['A']
    X = df_r[['B', 'C']]

    # i do some regression here

    print(np.mean(Y))
    print(np.max(Y))
```

When printing I get all values sequently based on classification value. So 14.580000000000002 and 43.6 is mean and max for rows which classification value is 1; 17.490909090909092 and 45.3 is mean and max for rows which classification value is 2 and so on,  like this:

```
14.580000000000002
43.6
17.490909090909092
45.3
29.599999999999998
67.9
14.766666666666666
29.3
```

But is is possible to print values in loop not for each classification group together? The results would look something like this:

```
print(np.mean(Y))
print(np.max(Y))
14.580000000000002
17.490909090909092
29.599999999999998
14.766666666666666
43.6
45.3
67.9
29.3
```

Here is the example of dataframe used in the example:

```
Out[281]: 
    id  clasification     A     B      C
0    1              1   5.4   7.4   59.6
1    2              2  44.2  49.9  244.0
2    3              3   5.5   8.8   42.4
3    4              1  10.5  14.9   82.6
4    5              1  13.6  19.8   93.7
5    6              1  12.9  18.2  103.4
6    7              1   7.4  10.5   50.9
7    8              2   7.4  10.9   54.2
8    9              2   8.2  11.7   55.8
9   10              2  10.0  13.5   55.8
10  11              2   6.0   8.2   29.3
11  12              2  45.3  63.9  392.7
12  13              2   9.5   9.4   53.7
13  14              2  23.9  32.9  226.6
14  15              3  46.7  63.9  406.2
15  16              3   7.8   8.6   44.4
16  17              3  35.8  49.9  343.6
17  18              3  67.9  87.5  609.9
18  19              2  14.8  20.6  120.3
```

Comment: I'd probably add a mean and max column rather than looping to do it.

Comment: That's a solution, yes! But as I have multiple other calculations, don't need to add multiple new columns to dataframe dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible without changing the structure of your code since without removing those prints inside the loop, each iteration will print sequentially a mean and a maximum. A suitable way to do as you'd like may be to save those values in lists and the print them at the end as follows

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\example..csv')

classif = list(set(data['clasification']))
# print(classif)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
means = []
maxes = []
for classif in classif:
    df_r = data[data['clasification'] == classif]

    Y = df_r['A']
    X = df_r[['B', 'C']]

    # i do some regression here

    means.append(np.mean(Y))
    maxes.append(np.max(Y))

print(means)
print(maxes)
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you are trying to do a `groupby` and some statistics. You can try

```
df.groupby('clasification').agg([mean,max])
```

prints

```
    id              A                   B           C
    mean        max mean         max    mean    max mean    max
clasification                               
1   4.600000    7   9.960000    13.6    14.160000   19.8    78.040000   103.4
2   10.888889   19  18.811111   45.3    24.555556   63.9    136.933333  392.7
3   13.800000   18  32.740000   67.9    43.740000   87.5    289.300000  609.9
```

`agg` function gives you quite a lot of control over what statistics to priont for what columns

you can even try

```
df.groupby('clasification').apply(lambda g:g.describe())
```

that will give you a bunch of aggregated stats per group